# Cordova Plugin for MQTT for ios?

Tags: ios, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins, mqtt

Is there a Cordova Plugin for MQTT for ios I did in Android. I search a lot for ios, but I couldn't get any good solution in detail. Please help..

Comment: Are you sure you've googled? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26436501/mqtt-over-websocket-for-android-and-ios

Answer (score 0):

Use this for MQTT ios plugin

[Click here for Cordova MQTT Plugin](https://github.com/roneyvia/MQTT-Worklight-Cordova-Plugin-For-IOS)

Answer (score -1):

```
See this link : https://github.com/arcoirislabs/cordova-plugin-mqtt
```

cordova-plugin-mqtt is plugin for building MQTT client for multiple platforms    in Apache Cordova. Currently Android platform is present and next support is    planned for iOS & Windows Phone.